# Posting to database from html form

Tags: html, database, forms, mongoose

I'm sure this is a simple thing I am missing but the internet seems devoid of the documentation to do this simple thing.

I am trying to grab data from my HTML and send it to my database. I forgot to add my script tag to the HTML for a while but it was working and sent two tests into the database before it stopped working and said my validations failed (both title and blog are required).

What am I missing? Thank you for your help!

my form:

```
<form
      action="/api/blog"
      method="POST"
      id="blog-form"
      class="blog-form container mt-5"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" />
  <br />
  <label for="blog">Text</label>
  <textarea name="blog" rows="15" cols="120"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
const form = document.getElementById("blog-form");
form.onsubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.value); // this is coming back undefined

};
```

API route:

```
router.post("/blog", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const blog = new Blog({
    title: req.body.title,
    blog: req.body.blog,
  });
  try {
    await blog.save();
    res.status(201).json(req.body);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("server error");
  }
```

Comment: I should also mention that I have an app.use("api", apiRoutes) on my server, so the route is api/blog

Answer (score 0):

got it working by removing the "enctype="multipart/form-data" from the HTML and removing all of the JS